# How do I get 16 bit sections of a 64 bit unsigned long using an integer index?

Tags: c, pointers, indexing, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to return certain 16-bit sections from a 64-bit unsigned long and I'm stuck on how to accomplish this. Here is the function I am trying to implement:

```
// assume i is a valid index (0-3 inclusive)
unsigned short get(unsigned long* ex, int i) {
  // return the 16-bit section based on the index i
}
```

For example, if I have `unsigned long ex = 0xFEDCBA9876543210;`, then my function `get(ex, 0)` would return `0x3210`, `get(ex, 1)` would return `0x7654`, etc. I'm very new to C and I'm still trying to wrap my head around bit management and pointers. Any advice or feedback is appreciated in helping me understand C better.

Comment: Multiply `i` by 16, shift `ex` that many bits to the right, and mask out unwanted bits by using an AND operation. In C code: `return (*ex >> (i << 4)) & 0xffff`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use a *bit shift*

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint16_t get(uint64_t ex, int i)
{
    return (uint16_t)(ex >> i*16);
}
```

You can just pass by value. There's no reason to pass a pointer. This will shift the bits to the right, meaning they become the low order value. When it gets converted to a 16 bit type, it loses the higher order bits.

I've included `stdint.h` because it defines types of *exact* size.

Comment: Possibly nicer to put an explicit cast on the return type: `return (uint16_t)(ex >> i*16);`. I would also put the `(i * 16)` term in brackets, to make it clearer (although `*` has higher precedence than `>>`).

Comment: @AdrianMole Good suggestion, but he'll have to learn about operator precedence eventually anyway.

Comment: nice use of stdint.h, it is a bit more clear than my answer

Answer (score 1):

I would use a mask along with bit shifting

```
unsigned short get(int index, unsigned long n)
{
    if (index > 3 || index < 0)
        return 0xFFFF; // well you have to see if you have control over the inputs.
    return (n >> (index << 4)) & 0xFFFF; // will extract 2 bytes.
}
```

Comment: `long` is not necessarily 64 bits.

Comment: Excellent point, thank you Windows. I was just assuming OP wants to use the same kind of types

Answer (score 0):

The way closest to what you're asking for is a union:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(const int argc, const char * const argv[]) {
    union {
        uint64_t i;
        uint16_t ia[4];
    } u;
    u.i = 0xFEDCBA9876543210;
    printf("u.ia[0] %x\n", u.ia[0]);
}
```

Output is:

```
u.ia[0] 3210
```